# nodejs this point undefined in function

Tags: node.js

Run this code in node.js v6.0.0:

```
x = 3;
var foo = {
  x:1,
  bar: {
    x: 2,
    baz: function() {
      console.log(this.x);
    }
  }
};

foo.bar.baz();
var a = foo.bar.baz;
a();
```

Error:

```
2
TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

But in chrome 52.0.2743.116 console:

```
2
3
```

Comment: It works for me with node v6.0.0. Are you sure you executed that same code you've shown in node?

Comment: Oh! It's different! Please change `x= 3` to `module.exports.x = 3` and run it in strict mode';

Comment: I know! In strict mode, this cann't point to global object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only occurs if you are in strict mode in ES6. In that case, top-level 'this' does not point to anything. Without 'use strict' (which is set implicitly when defining a module in Nodejs) the behaviour will be the same as you see in Chrome.

Note that for the code to work in strict mode however, you need to put a 'var'  before x=3.